# Viewing short values of chosen options in multiselect

Tags: html, angularjs, semantic-ui

below I attached some piece of code from https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html: (**Multiple Selection**)

```
<select name="skills" multiple="" class="ui fluid dropdown">
   <option value="">Skills</option>
   <option value="angular">Angular</option>
   <option value="css">CSS</option>
   <option value="design">Graphic Design</option>
   <option value="ember">Ember</option>
   <option value="html">HTML</option>
   <option value="ia">Information Architecture</option>
   <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
   <option value="mech">Mechanical Engineering</option>
   <option value="meteor">Meteor</option>
   <option value="node">NodeJS</option>
   <option value="plumbing">Plumbing</option>
   <option value="python">Python</option>
   <option value="rails">Rails</option>
   <option value="react">React</option>
   <option value="repair">Kitchen Repair</option>
   <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
   <option value="ui">UI Design</option>
   <option value="ux">User Experience</option>
</select>
```

The question is:
Is it possible to show short names of chosen options ?  I mean something like:
Options are:  `keyboard, mouse, monitor, laptop`
After chosing options `keyboard, mouse` shown are: `K, M`

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: _"After chosing options `keyboard`, `mouse` shown are: `K`, `M`"_ - and after `monitor` is chosen instead of `mouse`, or in addition to it ...?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with angular or semantic, but it is fairly easy using vanilaJS. You are welcome to test this code on semantic-ui website. Choose to items in the multi-select section then run this in the console:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".ui.label.transition.visible");
items.forEach(function(item){
    var icon = document.createElement("i");
    icon.className = "delete icon";
    item.innerText = item.innerText[0];
    item.appendChild(icon);
});
```

For sure to use it with angular you would like to modify my code but that is one possible approach.

Comment: From what is seems to me, as long as you would keep the `data-value` property it doesn't matter what is the text inside. So since you have component and you can control their text you should be able to present it each time with a different text but to keep the `data-value`. Sorry I don't have much knowledge about those libraries but from understanding the approach I am sure it would work. Post your answer after you figured it out :)